# Brownie + ganache-cli on Mac, some error shows up: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'poll'

Tags: python, chainlink

It is working fine on my server, but with local MacOS when executing `brownie run scripts/price_feed_scripts/01_deploy_price_consumer_v3.py --network development`, it is showing:

```
Launching 'ganache-cli --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --gasLimit 12000000 --mnemonic brownie --port 8545'...
Terminating local RPC client...
  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 43, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "brownie/network/main.py", line 50, in connect
    rpc.launch(active["cmd"], **active["cmd_settings"])
  File "brownie/network/rpc/__init__.py", line 97, in launch
    raise RPCConnectionError(cmd, self.process, uri)
  File "brownie/exceptions.py", line 41, in __init__
    f"\n\nCommand: {cmd}\nURI: {uri}\nExit Code: {proc.poll()}"
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'poll'
```

Comment: Can you please post the entire output including the command?

Comment: It's likely that you just don't have ganache installed. What happens when you run `ganache-cli` in your terminal?

Comment: I did install `ganache-cli` and the command `ganache-cli --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --gasLimit 12000000 --mnemonic brownie --port 8545` works fine in separated terminal.

Comment: When execute: `brownie run scripts/price_feed_scripts/01_deploy_price_consumer_v3.py --network development` and it will stop at: `Launching 'ganache-cli --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --gasLimit 12000000 --mnemonic brownie --port 8545` with above errror.

Comment: The same process on a different computer is fine. So no clue about what is going on in this computer.

Comment: Hmm.. Can you add the whole command and output?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be in the command that you ran for creating the 'development' network.

```
brownie networks add development mainnet-fork cmd=ganache-cli host=https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/XXX accounts=10 mnemonic=brownie port=8545
```

This is using wrong host and is missing the fork. The command should rather have been

```
brownie networks add development mainnet-fork cmd=ganache-cli host=http://127.0.0.1 fork=https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/XXX accounts=10 mnemonic=brownie port=8545
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, normally I am connected to a VPN and everything works fine. Today I turned it off and forgot to turn it on again. Then I had this issue. after some investigation, I thought about the VPN and there I go, after turning it back on, everything works fine again (1.1.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the command is unable to start the ganache instance on its own. You could try to start one manually on a different terminal and then run the command so that it attaches to the already running instance

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this issue, make sure you haven't specified your localhost with `https`, but with `http`. Took me a long time to see that small typo!

Answer (score 0):

I hat the same issue I solved by adding `host=http://127.0.0.1` be sure it's `http` not `HTTP` your command should be like :

```
`brownie networks add development mainnet-fork-dev cmd=ganache-cli host=http://127.0.0.1  fork=https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/DFwObAmnPwS21NdNsSLFkpV4C5YEkthH accounts=10 mnemonic=brownie port=9999`
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem by removing my terminal agent configs like 'export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1087', those configs will proxy your terminal http request. don't forget to restart your macos